# Are there frameworks for application-level (not DB) transactions (e.g. rollbacks)

Tags: java, servlets, frameworks, transactions

I use Java 1.6, Tomcat and servlets with JDBC and persistence frameworks.  I know (and use) DB level transactions, but I was wondering if there were frameworks for application level rollbacks and commits?

I'm sure there is a specific name for this, but something that let's me code and test the following in a more standard way than I currently implement it:

```
- get user info
- charge credit card
- create mailing labels
- write db
if any fail, then rollback and:
   - cancel credit card charge
   - invalidate mailing label
   - rollback DB
else
  - commit. (i.e. do it all with threads)
```

Does this even make sense?

So far, I'm handling all the logic and error checking... wondering if there is a nice framework to help as this gets more and more complex.

Comment: What if your server crashes and you don't get to do the extra processing which you need as well as your db rollback?

Comment: JDO's Transient Transactional is supposed to support this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about Spring framework ?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-programming-model

Let's say "charge credit card" and "create mailing labels" involve insertions in differente databases and message queues, you can rollback all these actions through a Spring transaction.

Comment: I realized that i had not accepted an answer. The latest Spring is pretty slick.

Comment: Well, Spring has been slick for 13 years to me, compared to the official J2EE/JEE EJB (talking about EJB 2 here)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are basically thinking of [software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory).  I'm not going to do much better than the Wikipedia summary:

> In computer science, software transactional memory (STM) is a concurrency control mechanism analogous to database transactions for controlling access to shared memory in concurrent computing. It is an alternative to lock-based synchronization. A transaction in this context is a piece of code that executes a series of reads and writes to shared memory. These reads and writes logically occur at a single instant in time; intermediate states are not visible to other (successful) transactions.

It's a very interesting idea, but I'm not aware of it really catching on in a "big way" yet.  I think it's mostly limited to research.  That said, doing a bit of searching around finds [Multiverse, a seemingly halfway interesting implementation](http://multiverse.codehaus.org/overview.html) which I've not heard of before but has a tutorial and website...

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like to me is we need a port of [System.Transactions.TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) with some customizable [IEnlistmentNotification](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31270/A-Transactional-Repository-Implementation-in-NET) implementations.  Perhaps [JDO Transactions](http://db.apache.org/jdo/transactions.html) does this stuff already, that is unclear to me at first glance.  On the surface it does not seem flexible enough to support other things like CC auth services and what not.